# Lebesgue differentiation theorem for Orlicz spaces

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis, orlicz-spaces

If $f\in L_{p}^{\rm loc}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and $1\leq p<\infty$, then a stronger version of Lebesgue differentiation theorem holds:  $$\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\|f\chi_{B(x,r)}\|_{L_{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}}{\|\chi_{B(x,r)}\|_{L_{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}}=|f(x)|$$ for almost all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. See, for example, "Grafakos, Classical Fourier Analysis, Third Edition, Page 101-102". Here $\chi_{B(x,r)}$ denotes the characteristic function of the open ball $B(x,r)$. I wonder that is there an analogue of this property in Orlicz spaces, that is, $$\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow0}\dfrac{\|f\chi_{B(x,r)}\|_{L_{\Phi}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}}{\|\chi_{B(x,r)}\|_{L_{\Phi}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}}=|f(x)|,$$ for almost all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ ?

Where $\Phi:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ is an increasing, continuous, convex function with $\Phi(0)=0$ and
$$
\|f\|_{L_{\Phi}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}:=\inf\{\lambda>0:\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\Phi\left(\frac{|f(x)|}{\lambda}\right)dx\leq 1\}.
$$
It is a generalization of $L_p$ norm. Indeed, if we take $\Phi(t)=t^p,\,1\leq p< \infty$ we get $\|f\|_{L_{\Phi}}=\|f\|_{L_{p}}$.

Comment: Probably so. Continuous functions have this property, and are dense in the Orlicz space. Given $f$ as above, write $f=g+h$ where $g$ is continuous and $h$ has norm $<\epsilon$. Then $\int \Phi(|h|/\epsilon)\le 1$. Apply the weak $(1,1)$ property of maximal function to $\Phi(|h|/\epsilon)$. Hopefully it will show that the set where $h$ substantially contributes to the ratio has small measure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Simple functions are dense in Orlicz space provided that $\Phi$ satisifes doubling condition, i.e., there exist $C>0$ such that $\Phi(2t)\leq C\Phi(t)$ for all $t>0$. So you mean that my question is true provided that $\Phi$ satisifes doubling condition, am i right ?  I couldn't see what i will do after applying weak $(1,1)$ property of maximal function. Can you write more clearly, please ?

Comment: @Woodface is the following an alternative method: define a maximal function such that
$$
M^{\Phi}f(x)=\sup_{r>0}\dfrac{\|f\chi_{B(x,r)}\|_{L_{\Phi}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}}{\| \chi_{B(x,r)}\|_{L_{\Phi}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}}
$$
and obtain a weak type inequality for this operator. As an application of this we get the desired equation. Unfortunately, i couldn't do any of these operations. I need your helps.

Comment: Please see the following post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663314/analogue-of-lebesgue-differentiation-theorem-in-orlicz-spaces